# What is the syntax in Office add-ins to display a child Javascript element?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

**On clicking the Show options button, a list needs to be displayed but it is not working.**
This is for the user interaction aspect for what the user will click or type into the free form text field, that should have an event listener to perform an action. To perform this action, the Javascript code is very direct and it works when you run the html file on the browser - it is simple straight-forward javascript code. However, on excel you cannot use the same syntax when storing or analysing user input. For excel add-ins you will have to add separate syntax. For eg, something like addEventListener.Microsoft.Office(...). I cannot find this exact syntax that needs to be added for the code to work on the Excel add-in, nor can I find its documentation.

Here is my code that works fine on my Browser console :

```
var clicked = false;

function add_train() {
  if(!clicked){
    clicked= true;
    
    let list = select('#data');
    let input = [ 
    {
      sentence : "Convert report to pie chart",
      category : "piechart"
    },
    {
      sentence: "Convert report to bar chart",
      category : "barchart"
    },
    {
       sentence: "Convert report to pivot table",
       category : "pivottable"
    } 
    ]
    for ( i =0 ; i < input.length ; i++) {
    if (input[i].sentence != "" &&  input[i].category != "") {
      classifier.train(input[i].sentence, input[i].category);
  
      elem = createElement('li', input[i].sentence);
      list.child(elem);
      // This function is fully functional Javascript code but requires modification to work in Excel add-in

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume that this is a task pane add-in. JavaScript that manipulates the DOM in the task pane or handles events in the task pane is the same as JavaScript in a regular web app that runs in a browser. The Office.js library is used to interact with the Excel workbook. It is not used for work that is internal to the task pane.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thank you very much for the clarification. Instead of going ahead with a JavaScript add-in, should I use VSTO to create a COM add-in? If yes where can I find the documentation for the same?

Comment: The documentation for VSTO add-ins begins here: [Create VSTO Add-ins for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2017). VSTO add-ins run only on Windows machines. They cannot be used in **Office on the web** or **Office on Mac**. That is the primary thing to keep in mind when deciding which type of add-in to create.

Comment: @RickKirkham thank you for your help! I have started with a VSTO Web Add-in for Excel using .NET framework and done using VBA. However I am again stuck in this same part. I want to simply display a list(the key value of the JavaScript object) by clicking a button on the taskpane. And this child element (i,e the list)  is able to be displayed on the web console with the same code. However, does not happen on the add-in, I believe the syntax needs to be manipulated to adjust to the Office add-in syntax. I would also like to ask for the Office documentation for textual input taken from the user.

Comment: I don't believe there is a web console in a VSTO add-in. At any rate, since you are now working on a VSTO add-in, you should create a new Stack Question. Use `vsto` as a tag and do not tag it `office-js` and `javascript`.